# Saving Camera Photo To Gallery From Fragment using File Provider

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am following along with [Googles Official](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto) docs on how to save a picture take with the camera to the gallery.

They want you to create a file using `getExternalFilesDir`.

```
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

         String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + UUID.randomUUID();
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

**mCurrentPhotoPath** is equal to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_22fda6f2-dad9-4dd9-b327-c1130c8df0eb187766077.jpg`

But in the very next section, the most important section, **Add the Photo to a Gallery**,

They say:

> If you saved your photo to the directory provided by
>   getExternalFilesDir(), the media scanner cannot access the files
>   because they are private to your app.

Which is the exact method `getExternalFilesDir()` they used. :-(

So I looked at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) on that too. And I don't understand well enough yet to figure out which directory method I need to use. I tried `getFilesDir()` but it doesn't like the `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`.

But they do not offer  a way to save to the gallery using their method. Their code snippet doesn't work

```
private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPUTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAPUTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                galleryAddPic();

        }
        }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

So my app does **NOT** save a picture to the gallery. I don't see where it saves it at all.

**Anyone know what I did wrong?**

Comment: "Which is the exact method they used" -- that passage from the documentation is incorrect. `getExternalFilesDir()` is *unique* to your app, but it is not *private* to your app. "Their code snippet doesn't work" -- try `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method.

Comment: I tried that and the photo is never saved to my camera roll.

Answer (score 1):

When you add files to Android’s filesystem these files are not picked up by the MedaScanner automatically, also Android runs a full media scan only on reboot. The problem is that a full scan is taking long time.

One solution is using the static scanFile() method. If you simply need to know when the files have been added, you could use [MediaScannerConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html)’s static method **scanFile()** together with a [MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener.html). The static method **scanFile()** is badly named, as it actually takes an array of paths and thus can be used to add multiple files at once and not just one, but it nevertheless does what we want.
Here’s how to use this method:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
  getApplicationContext(),
  new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
  null,
  new OnScanCompletedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Log.v("grokkingandroid",
              "file " + path + " was scanned seccessfully: " + uri);
     }
  });
```

the below information is the parameters for the static **scanFile()** method.

- **context** : The application context
- **paths** : A String array containing the paths of the files you want to add
- **mimeTypes** : A String array containing the mime types of the files
- **callback** : A MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener to be notified when the scan is completed

The **OnScanCompletedListener** itself must implement the **onScanCompleted()** method. This method gets the filename and the URI for the **MediaStore.Files** provider passed in as parameters.

I hope this will help.